# Attaching multiple click events with same div in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one div and there are two events associated with it first is  a click and another a popover trigger which also gets triggered on click .

Now with first click i need to modify the href attribute of the div and second popover event should pick this modified href and opens up a popover with content fetched from href.

The problem i am facing (looks liek to me ) is second popover triggers still picks up old value and appears to me that the sequence/order in which i registered the events is not maintained . How can I solve this problem.

Here is the my code sample:

```
retVal = originalURL;

retVal = jQuery('#'+'linkhere').click(getHashPageClick); // thsi function returns a href
(the value is correctly returned )

jQuery('#'+'linkhere').popoverTrigger(retVal); // thsi function opens up a popover with contents fetched from href URL.
```

but its still picking original URL. Can someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call the popovertrigger after you call the gethashpage. That should do the trick.

```
jQuery('#'+'linkhere').click( function() {
  getHashPageClick();
  popOvertrigger();
})
```

Remember you can specifcy a function to your click function, so you can do a chain of events there

Comment: Is there any other way to get this done. I cannot have more than one function defined inside click .

Comment: why cant you have more than one? yes, you can call popovertrigger INSIDE gethashpageclick

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the order the events are firing. There may be a tricky solution using event propagation and bubbling and other fancy things, but there's a simpler solution.  Just use `mousedown`!

`$('#'+'linkhere').mousedown(getHashPageClick);`

[image: Firebug Example]